# Value of this in protoypal object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor, this

I'm trying something like this:

```
(function() {
  var Foo, foo;

  Foo = function(proto) {
    var obj, privateMethod, publicMethod;
    privateMethod = function() {
      return console.log("private", this);
    };
    publicMethod = function() {
      console.log("public", this);
      return privateMethod();
    };
    obj = Object.create(proto);
    obj.bar = publicMethod;
    return obj;
  };

  foo = new Foo({
    baz: "dooz"
  });

  foo.bar();

}).call(this);
```

Obviously this is the object itself when publicMethod is called, but is set to the global object in the privateMethod. I know it can be solved by changing:

```
      return privateMethod();
```

to:

```
      return privateMethod.call(this);
```

I know that this get's lost when a function is nested in a function, but did not expect that case here. Do I encounter this JavaScript bug here or is there something that I simply do not understand yet?

Comment: You might have problems wtih Object.create since it's not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Im not sure that would explain the scope differences between the private and public function.  Even if you were to explicitly define the proto object with bar pointing to the public function, the scope remains the same.  This is interesting.  On a side note, why .call on the anonymous function passing the window object when you can just () to self invoke?

Comment: @croteau:  why .call on the anonymous function passing the window object when you can just () to self invoke? - cause this references the object itself not the global and simply using () does not work, cause privateMethod is no property of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context (`this`), in javascript, is set by how a function is called, and is in no way a property of the function itself.

```
obj.bar = function() { console.log(this) };
obj.bar()    // obj
obj['bar']() // obj

// But break the function off the object, and this changes
fn = obj.bar
fn() // window
```

What this example shows us is that the the dot syntax there sets `this`.  Think of `obj.bar()` is syntax sugar for `obj.bar.call(obj)`.

So your public method gets the right `this`, because of how it's called in external code.

```
foo.bar();
```

But your private method is invoked with no receiver at all.

```
return privateMethod();
```

So no context is assigned, and it defaults to the global object.

---

So given you are creating these functions in the constructor, you have some flexibility.

You could assign the proper value of `this` in the constructor to something else, and use that in your private functions. (Likely the best option)

```
var self = this;
privateMethod = function() {
  return console.log("private", self);
};
```

Or if your JS target engine support `Function.prototype.bind` (not all do, sadly) you could do:

```
privateMethod = function() {
  return console.log("private", this);
}.bind(this);
```

Which will return a function that has an assigned context, no matter what.

Or you could bind it manually yourself.

```
_privateMethod = function() {
  return console.log("private", this);
}

Foo = function(proto) {
  privateMethod = function() {
    _privateMethod.call(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `foo.bar()`.  This means the function `bar()` is called on `foo`, meaning `this` is `foo` inside `bar()`.

In your case `foo` is <strike>a `Foo` object</strike> `obj`, and `bar()` is `publicMethod`.

When `publicMethod()` calls `privateMethod()`, there's no context, so `this` becomes the global `this` (`window`).